# flow.collect(suspend (T) -> Unit) doesn't work with the newer version of coroutines dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I updated the gradle file

from

```groovy
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'
```

to

```groovy
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0'
```

What happened was that the following function started to throw error.

```
fun <T> Fragment.collectLifeCycleFlow(flow: Flow<T>, collector: suspend (T) -> Unit) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            flow.collect(collector)
        }
    }
}
```

However, it works fine with flow.collectLatest(collector)

I don't know why collect() doesn't accept parameters anymore. Please help with me.

Comment: Could you please write down the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Flow.collect` now takes a FlowCollector functional interface argument instead of a `suspend (T) -> Unit`.

This function was always there, but it was marked with an annotation that prevented you from using it and there was a separate `collect` extension function that adapted `suspend (T) -> Unit` into a `FlowCollector<T>`. Now the base `collect` function is publicly usable and they removed that extension function. The plus side is you no longer have to deal with having to manually import the extension function. The previous behavior caused `collect` to not compile, but the IDE didn't suggest how to import the extension function in an easy manner.

By the way, you should be using `viewLifecycleOwner` in a Fragment!

Here is your fixed code:

```
fun <T> Fragment.collectLifeCycleFlow(flow: Flow<T>, collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            flow.collect(collector)
        }
    }
}
```